# Query for Triangles within or intersecting Bounding Box

Tags: c++

I've have a working code on octree structure that stores points and this can be used in querying the tree for points within a bounding box....but the next situation is, is it possible for an octree structure to store "triangles" and we'll be querying the tree for triangles "within" (triangle size is smaller than bounding box) or "intersecting" (triangle size is larger than bounding box) the bounding box..? If "yes", please do explain how...

For example, I've a list of triangles (thousands or more) and I need to find whether a particular bounding box is intersected with triangle/s...I've a working code on detecting whether a bounding box is intersected with a triangle or not...but now I'm trying to find a faster and efficient way to detect which triangle is intersecting the box instead of using brute force (going through every triangle in test for intersections)...hence, I'm thinking of combining this with an octree structure (fast querying)....or are there any other ways to do it...? many thanks in advance...

I'm not using VTK, OpenGL, TetGen, CGAL, or any other complex libraries....just basic C++ software which is CodeBlocks.

Comment: Store the three points defining the vertices of the triangle in the octree, along without enough extra data for each vertex to find the other two vertexes of that triangle.

Comment: @JerryCoffin - what do you mean by "along without enough extra data"..?

Comment: Oops--that should read "along *with* enough extra data..."

Comment: @JerryCoffin - what if the query box does not contain any of the vertices but still intersects with the triangle (triangle size is larger)..? I'm sorry as I'm still new to this octree method....as far as i know...the octree code that i developed above is getting points found within a certain query box....so i was thinking if i were to store all vertices of triangles along with a getTriangle() function that relates to each vertices, this will only solve for triangle size is smaller than query box....i'm sorry if it sounds confusing

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking only of the "within" part, not the "intersecting" part of your question.